# Unable to connect to vnc server on rpi2 (raspbian pixel desktop)

Tags: pi-2, vnc

I have a rpi2 running the latest raspbian image with Pixel desktop. I enabled ssh and vnc in raspi config. Rpi is connected to my home network over ethernet and has an IP address. I'm also able to ssh into it from my Linux laptop. However, I cannot connect to the now running vnc server.
I'm using Remmina remote desktop client from my Ubuntu laptop.

The error message says something like "connection refused. authentication scheme is not known".

As I understand, after enabling VNC server from the raspi-config GUI, connections from clients should just work. Anyone else seen this? Kindly help.

Thanks and regards,

Aashish.

P.S. I have used RealVNC vnc server on my rpi before (earlier raspbian versions) and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The message indicates that the client and server can not agree on a secure connection mechanism. I have seen this with other VNC viewers. The simplest solution is to download [RealVNC Viewer](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/) which is available for Windows, Linux, Mac OS X as well as IOS and Android.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I will try with RealVNC client and see if it solves the problem. If not, I'll install the server on rpi myself too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access using a browser at the http://**ip_address_raspberry:5800**

The browser could start a vnc java applet by clicking on applet button.

Comment: does this still work with the latest feb 2017 release?